# GetComponentInParent<Image>() Does not change the parent's component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted the child to change the color image component of the parent, as the player clicked the child.
here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DragOption : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{

   public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
   {
      GetComponentInParent<Image>().color = new Color32(255, 235, 0, 255);
   }
}
```

But instead of the parent getting changed to the new color, it was the child that got changed. is there a fix to these?

Answer (score 0):

[`GetComponentInParent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInParent.html) includes the component search on the calling object itself.

> Returns the component of Type type **in the GameObject o**r any of its parents.

So if your "child" also has an `Image` component itself (which is the case if I understand you correctly) it will return that one.

---

In order to be sure it starts at least one parent above you would rather want to do

```
transform.parent.GetComponentInParent<Image>().color = new Color32(255, 235, 0, 255);
```

or if you are sure anyway that the direct parent is the one you want you can directly do

```
transform.parent.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(255, 235, 0, 255);
```